# Formula in Excel to find cell's value, which is a sub-string of a given string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

All.

Just in case if someone have seen this kind of problem before and/or can think about an elegant solution…

I am looking for a formula for cell E3, that’ll fill it with 
the first matching ID of a requirement, 
if it’s listed in “linked items” column of DEFECTS table 
and reqID column of table REQUIREMENTS.

[image to illustrate](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85905383/1.png) or sample [excel file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85905383/sample.xlsx).

P.S.: I know only one solution, but it’s definitely not an elegant one and provided that we have thousands of records in both tables, makes whole Excel file huge and not usable on a normal PC (3GB of memory and all CPU resources always consumed when this 178Mb file is open).

Comment: The formula will look like this: string (some property of the product I'm not sure), range1, range2. For each row in range1 if there's a match then put it in an array. For each row in range2 if there's a match and the ID is present in your array then you've found it, set it and exit function. Good luck programming it.

Comment: Can you please provide a more definite solution?

Comment: We're not providing programming services (some of us do, for a living). If you show some sort of code that you have tried and point out where it's not working as you have intended we may help. If you don't have the slightest idea on how to grasp something we may help. [That's what we do.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Comment: Mate, why to waste your time replying here at all, if you don't want to provide a solution? All the "code" I need is a formula in Excel. And my (not so good) solution is in the file, linked to the 1st reply to this question. You might have misread the question: I'm not looking for a VBA function, but for a formula to be used in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is in [this file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85905383/sample_less_ugly_solution.xlsx).

It's not exactly ideal as assumes that 
1. list of linked items is comma-delimited
2. there are not more than 10 items linked to one defect…